# Nothing showing in my lists

Tags: php, cakephp

I have some lists, but none of them are being populated. I'm using the exact same method of populating my lists as I have done in other controllers, which have no problems.

Here is the add function of my controller:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->ConsumerProduct->create();
        if ($this->ConsumerProduct->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The consumer product has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The consumer product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $products = $this->ConsumerProduct->Product->find('list');
    $legacyProducts = $this->ConsumerProduct->LegacyProduct->find('list');
    $unitStatuses = $this->ConsumerProduct->UnitStatus->find('list');
    $addresses = $this->ConsumerProduct->find('list', 'Address.id');
    $this->set(compact('products', 'legacyProducts', 'unitStatuses', 'addresses'));
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing the problem?

Also I previous had `$addresses = $this->ConsumerProduct->find('list', 'Address.id');` set to `$addresses = $this->ConsumerProduct->Address->find('list');` but that gave me the following error:

`Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object`

Is this related?

Edit:

Relationships are as follows:

`ConsumerProduct` belongsTo `Product, LegacyProduct, UnitStatus, Address`

`Address` hasMany `ConsumerProduct`

`LegacyProduct` hasMany `ConsumerProduct`

`UnitStatus` hasMany `ConsumerProduct`

`Address` hasMany `ConsumerProduct`

`Product` has no relation to `ConsumerProduct` within it's model

Edit 2:

`Address.php`

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Address Model
 *
 * @property User $User
 * @property Company $Company
 * @property ConsumerProduct $ConsumerProduct
 */
class Address extends AppModel {

/**
 * Primary key field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Company' => array(
            'className' => 'Company',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(

        'ConsumerProduct' => array(
            'className' => 'ConsumerProduct',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

`ConsumerProduct.php`

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');


/**
 * ConsumerProduct Model
 *
 * @property Product $Product
 * @property LegacyProduct $LegacyProduct
 * @property UnitStatus $UnitStatus
 * @property addresses $Addresses
 * @property Review $Review
 */
class ConsumerProduct extends AppModel {

/**
 * Primary key field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        /*'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),*/
        'LegacyProduct' => array(
            'className' => 'LegacyProduct',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'UnitStatus' => array(
            'className' => 'UnitStatus',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Review' => array(
            'className' => 'Review',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'className' => 'addresses',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

`Product.php`

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Product Model
 *
 * @property serials $Serials
 * @property Category $Category
 * @property ProductStatus $ProductStatus
 * @property ProductReward $ProductReward
 */
class Product extends AppModel {

/**
 * Primary key field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'name';


/**
 * hasOne associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasOne = array(
        'Serials' => array(
            'className' => 'serials',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'ProductStatus' => array(
            'className' => 'ProductStatus',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'ProductReward' => array(
            'className' => 'ProductReward',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'ConsumerProduct' => array(
            'className' => 'ConsumerProduct',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: could be useful to know the relation between models, and if all lists are failing. Also, could you do `pr($addresses)` to know if it is a controller or view issue?

Comment: @Nunser pr($addresses) returns blank. I'm fairly sure it's a controller or model issue. I've also edited in the relationships in my main post.

Comment: Probably a relation issue, could you update with your Address.php and ConsumerProduct.php? You put the relations here, but maybe it's a typo or something.

Comment: @Nunser thanks for bearing with me. I've edited in the models you requested as well as `Product.php`, my addresses list has now been populated after I changed the relationship in `ConsumerProduct.php` from `belongsTo` to `hasMany` `Address`. Doing the same with the other models didn't work, but maybe this is a clue as to what's going wrong?

Comment: first, you should use `$addresses = $this->ConsumerProduct->Address->find('list');` this. You said it gives you problems, but that is the correct way. And that problem can be solved fixing this `'Address' => array(
            'className' => 'addresses',` in your ConsumerProduct code (should be `'className` => 'Address'`)

Comment: @Nunser I've made those changes and my address list is being populated, thanks! However I tried the same fix on the other lists but they're still empty, do you have an idea why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

"Product", "LegacyProduct" and "UnitStatus" are models? If yes declare then before the find with [loadModel](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::loadModel)

After use $this->Product->find(...) ...

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I'd previously tried this. It has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ConsumerProduct.php` in `$hasMany` array for you `'className' => 'addresses'` it should be `'className' => 'Address'` instead (and model should also be `Address`).

In general avoid specifying `className` key if your class names are as per conventions and you are not actually aliasing a model.